# UIView drawRect black Window

Tags: objective-c, ios, drawrect, core-text

This is my drawRect method.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
[super drawRect:rect];
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable(); //1
CGPathAddRect(path, NULL, self.bounds );

NSAttributedString* attString = [[[NSAttributedString alloc]
    initWithString:@"Hello core text world!"] autorelease]; //2

CTFramesetterRef framesetter =
    CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((CFAttributedStringRef)attString); //3
CTFrameRef frame =
    CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter,
        CFRangeMake(0, [attString length]), path, NULL);

CTFrameDraw(frame, context); //4

CFRelease(frame); //5
CFRelease(path);
CFRelease(framesetter);
}
```

Once I load this view in my view controller, the window become black. If I comment the drawRect method, everything go ok.. Where is the mistake?

Comment: You shouldn't need to call [super drawRect:rect]; since "The default implementation of this method does nothing"

Comment: I tried, nothing changed. Thanks anyway..

Comment: The docs for CTFrameDraw says: "This call can leave the context in any state and does not flush it after the draw operation." Have you tried inserting `CGContextFlush(context);` after CTFrameDraw? It "Forces all pending drawing operations".

Comment: Something strange happened. If i load this view from a nib, everything works fine... Has anyone some ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem creating a viewController with my custom uiview inside. Not really what I wanted, but it works..

Comment: Hang on, you had `drawRect` in your view controller? If so, then yes, that won't work! `drawRect` is a method of `UIView`.

Comment: Oh no, the drawRect method was in the UIView! That would be a very stupid question to ask ;)

Comment: Then why did creating another view controller with the custom view inside work? How did it differ from what you originally did?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the background colour to transparent

```
 viewName.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Was attempting to draw simple circles. Created a simple `UIView` subclass, overrode `drawRect` and there was always a black square rendered behind the circles.

```
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

in the init fixed it!